# SharePoint 2010 Custom Action EnableScript function

Tags: sharepoint, custom-action

I added a custom action to SharePoint list. In CommandUIHandler in EnableScript attribute I added a javascript function. Then I realised that it is being invoked twice. To be more specific:
1) When I enter a default view for the list and click "Items" in a Ribbon it is invoked once
2) When I select checkbox near the list item it is invoked twice?
I have some queries loading in a background so I don't want it to be called twice. Does anyone know whether it's a bug or SharePoint default behaviour?

```
<CustomAction
 Id="Ribbon.Documents.TestGroup.AssignCard"
 Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
 RegistrationId="10001"
 RegistrationType="List"
 ShowInLists="TRUE"
 Sequence="26">
<CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
            <Button
                    Id="Ribbon.Documents.TestGroup.AssignCard"
                    LabelText="Assign"
                    ToolTipTitle="Assign a free card"
                    ToolTipDescription="Opens a form to assign a free card to a guest."
                    Alt="Assign"
                    Sequence="31"
                    Command="AssignButtonCommand"
                    Image32by32="/_layouts/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png"
                    Image32by32Top="-160"
                    Image32by32Left="-288"
                    TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
            Command="AssignButtonCommand"
            CommandAction="javascript: document.ReceptionRibbon.AssignButton({SiteUrl}, {SelectedItemId});"
             EnabledScript="javascript: console.log('1'); document.ReceptionRibbon.EnableAssignButton();" />
    </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by setting a temporary boolean variable to false when query starts, and setting it back to true when it ends.